# 'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command when installing package

Tags: opencv, pkg-config

So I'm getting this error when attempting to install OpenCV on my computer.

```
'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I've been searching around for this pkg-config package and I can't seem to find a proper download source anywhere.

The only one I did find was pkg-config-lite. I tired to see if that one would work but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The original pkg-config release is available here:
  http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config