# How to Aliviate this error about Mission Pinball Framework

Tags: python

I have tried to install this piece of software, called mission pinball framework. I have tried and installed G Streamer (Or at least I have).

Here is the error that keeps cropping up:

```
(mpfenv) C:\Users\---Name Redacted----->pip install mpf[all] mpf-mc

Collecting mpf[all]

  Using cached mpf-0.55.0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)

  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done

Collecting mpf-mc

  Using cached mpf-mc-0.55.0.tar.gz (13.0 MB)

 Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

   command: 'C:\Users\username\mpfenv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools,

 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ben Madison\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f2n2t9px

\\mpf-mc_c739650107be4bf39672b8ddc3b25343\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\--Name 

Redacted--\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f2n2t9px\\mpf-mc_c739650107be4bf39672b8ddc3b25343

\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) 

else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r

\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 

'C:\Users\---Name Redacted ----\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-mvmd5lbx'
       
cwd: C:\Users\--Name Redacted--\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f2n2t9px\mpf-

mc_c739650107be4bf39672b8ddc3b25343\

  Complete output (16 lines):

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    
File "C:\Users\--Name Redacted---\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f2n2t9px\mpf-

mc_c739650107be4bf39672b8ddc3b25343\setup.py", line 354, in <module>

      raise RuntimeError('GStreamer not found and is required to build MPF-MC')

  RuntimeError: GStreamer not found and is required to build MPF-MC

  Using setuptools

  Skipping Cython build (using .c files)

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch 

file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch 

file.\r\n"

  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/a1/a9d1ca07422f63baa50a94f1bcc71f3306eb736b840681c536ac5d1da732/mpf-mc-0.55.0.tar.gz#sha256=ee1033c5c63704badaf6af6887faaf6e6c13ef803837698f26323183294cc5aa (from https://pypi.org/simple/mpf-mc/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What do I need to do, to stop getting this error?

Currently running Windows 10 with up to date Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command when installing package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841199/pkg-config-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-when-installin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pkg config in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows/25605631)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No both those do not.